# Postman/Newman - args for beforeIteration event cursor attribute with has two attributes - cycles and iterations - what is the difference?

Tags: postman

The `beforeIteration` event `args.cursor` has following attributes (as displayed in the following details for first iteration)

```
  position: 0,
  iteration: 0,
  length: 4,
  cycles: 1,
  empty: false,
  eof: false,
  bof: true,
  cr: false,
  ref: <some_id>
```

What is the difference between the cycles and the iterations attribute?
I have looked into https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-runtime and other online resources but could not find the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iteration is how many times you want tests to run. As of the cycles argument, you are right, it is not documented anywhere.

Comment: Yes - iterations is clear but `cycles` is the one i am interested in